# Is it still possible to use .NET Framework (4.8) for ASP.NET Core 3 with Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: asp.net-core

Today I installed .net Fw 4.8 dev pack together **.net core SDK 3.01**. After reboot I notice that *ASP.NET CORE wizard*, when I select .net fw don't display ASP.NET CORE 3 (*I see until 2.2*). Instead, if I select on the left dropdown .net core I get ASP.NET CORE 3 (and the previous versions)

[image: image no.1 - .net core]

[image: image no.2 - .net FW 4.8]

Comment: No, [ASP.NET Core 3.0 will only run on .Net Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/324)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggest by Kanbazi on comment, ASP.NET CORE 3 only run on .NET CORE.

[link](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/324)